# How to rename files in file from lines of a text file

Tags: powershell, rename, find-and-replace

My script PowerShell:

```
$liste = get-content "Y:\Users\H\Documents\D\Game Of Throne\prod\recup.txt" `
         |Select-Object -last 1

$liste | ForEach-Object {Write-Host ($i++) $line}

get-childItem "Y:\Users\H\Documents\D\Game Of Throne\*.bmp*" `
       | rename-item -newname { $_.name -replace("aaa",$line)}
```

Example of files to rename: `GameOfThrone aaa.bmp; GameOfThrone aaa(2).bmp ...`

In text file:

```
A
B
C
```

I want my files named as follows: `GameOfThrone A.bmp; GameOfThrone B.bmp ...`

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to achieve. Please rephrase your question and list the file contents.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Automate script | Rename a defined list of filename by a defined list of word powershell](http://superuser.com/questions/927127/automate-script-rename-a-defined-list-of-filename-by-a-defined-list-of-word-po)